# Management and execution of processes at a desired time

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

GOAL: For example, the user types in the message, selects a date and time, and the message will be sent at that time.

My current approach is far from the best, and I am looking for some guidance as to what the best way to do this would be.

My Approach:
1. Entry is added to an sql database
2. Url (e.x. localhost:8080/webservices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WebSceduler?refresh) is called to tell a Tomcat service that there are new items
3. The service then hits the database, finds the new (and/or removed) messages and then
4. creates a new quartz job that executes at the time in the database, sending the message.

I can certainly tell that this is not the best approach, but maybe there are a few things I was on the right track about.